# App works in debug before package creation, but instantly crashes after creating packages

Tags: uwp, visual-studio-2019

Developing a UWP app which to submit to the store requires package creation. In development, I am able to run and debug the app. Everything runs as expected. However, as soon as I create packages to upload to the store, neither Visual Studio, nor AppCert can launch the app.

After searching Google, Bing and anywhere else I could find, the suggestions that I was able to find and try were:

- Delete the bin and obj files, cleaning the solution and then rebuilding the solution.
- and rewriting the code to a new solution

Both times the results were the same. I am currently using Visual Studio 2019 Community, on a windows 10 device.

I am referencing a few things other than the default packages to extend the usability of this app including a package to allow some backwards compatibility for the menu bar, and Telerik UI for UWP to allow data visualization.

How can I fix this to get my next app update out?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Issues specific to programming and software development are off topic, see [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try [SO] but please first read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @DavidPostill I definitely disagree with this as it is a problem with visual studio and AppCert. This is not a programming question. I know my code works but still visual studio and AppCert are crashing it

Comment: "visual studio and AppCert are crashing it" clearly your code does not work ...

Comment: My code works right up until I push create app packages. clearly it works

Comment: It's still off -topic.

Comment: in what way this about troubleshooting a problem with a software, thus it is ON TOPIC

Comment: Because it is about software development with is off topic. If you don't agree raise this issue on meta not in comments.